# Application dependency to ViewModel with HILT

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I was wondering how can I pass application dependency to ViewModel using Hilt?
I was trying with AndroidViewModel, but I couldn't make it. Can someone help me? Some short sample could will mean a lot to me.

This is my ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val application: Application,
    private val repository: Repository,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
```

This is my hilt module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        MyDatabase::class.java,
        "my_database"
    ).build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDao(database: MyDatabase) = database.myDao()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRepository(myDao: MyDao) = Repository(myDao)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApplicationContext() = MyApplication()

}
```

Everything else is fine, and I got the error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of
> class com.example.example.viewmodel.MainViewModel
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.example.example.viewmodel.MainViewModel> has
> no zero argument constructor

Comment: StefanJo, Is there any solution you have achieved passing application instance in AndroidViewModel using hilt?

Answer (score 2):

You can see full source https://github.com/Kotlin-Android-Open-Source/MVI-Coroutines-Flow/tree/dagger_hilt

- Repository:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val userApiService: UserApiService,
    private val dispatchers: CoroutineDispatchers,
    ...
) : UserRepository { ... }
```

- Usecases:

```kotlin
class AddUserUseCase @Inject constructor(private val userRepository: UserRepository) {
  suspend operator fun invoke(user: User) = userRepository.add(user)
}

class RemoveUserUseCase @Inject constructor(private val userRepository: UserRepository) {
  suspend operator fun invoke(user: User) = userRepository.remove(user)
}

class RefreshGetUsersUseCase @Inject constructor(private val userRepository: UserRepository) {
  suspend operator fun invoke() = userRepository.refresh()
}

...
```

- ViewModel:

```kotlin
class MainVM @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val getUsersUseCase: GetUsersUseCase,
    private val refreshGetUsers: RefreshGetUsersUseCase,
    private val removeUser: RemoveUserUseCase,
) : ViewModel() { ... }
```

- Activity:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View {
  private val mainVM by viewModels<MainVM>()
  
  ...
}
```

## Edited:

To inject application context:

### First, remove this definition, because `Hilt` already provides application context:

```kotlin
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApplicationContext() = MyApplication()
```

### Second, Use @ApplicationContext annotation on your context parameter.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val repository: Repository,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
```

Comment: But you dont have application passed in parameters..

Comment: Updated answer,  hope to help you

Comment: This shows a warning `This field leaks a context object`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ApplicationContext Context context` as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Voted down without a comment? Why?