# How can I dependency injection Context into ViewModel using Hilt in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

Before, I use Code A to pass `Context` to `ViewModel`.

Now I hope to use Hilt as dependency injection to pass `Context`,

I have  read the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565943/application-dependency-to-viewmodel-with-hilt) , and Code B is from the article.

1: Is the Code B correct way to pass `Context` into `ViewModel`?

2: In my mind, in order to use Hilt in Android Studio project, I have added such as the Code C in project, do I need to use `fun provideApplicationContext() = MyApplication()` in Code B?

**Code A**

```
class HomeViewModel(private val mApplication: Application, val mRepository: DBRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
  ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val repository: Repository,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
}


@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideApplicationContext() = MyApplication()
```

**Code C**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I injected applicationContext in the viewmodel and it worked fine.

**Base Application**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication: Application()
```

**App Module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideApplication(@ApplicationContext app: Context):   BaseApplication{
    return app as BaseApplication
}
```

**View Model**

```
@HiltViewModel
class PendingListViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val application: BaseApplication)
```

**Usage In the ViewModel**

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(application.applicationContext, R.drawable.marker_circle)
```