# How can I dependency injection Context with Hilt for ViewModel() in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I hope to dependency injection Context with Hilt for ViewModel,

I have read the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565943/application-dependency-to-viewmodel-with-hilt), and Code A based the article.

But I get the following warning information, why? How can I fix it?

**This field leaks a context object**

BTW, I have read the [article](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/03/inject-context-with-hilt-this-field.html), and my project is `hilt_version = '2.41'` .

**Code A**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val mContext: Context,  //It cause  a warning information
    private val aSoundMeter: ISoundMeter  
): ViewModel() {


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`

```
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val mContext: Application,
    private val aSoundMeter: ISoundMeter  
): AndroidViewModel(mContext)
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code can't be compiled, `Type mismatch.
Required:
Application
Found:
Context`

Comment: @HelloCW It's my fault. Check my update.

Comment: Thanks! Your code can't use Hilt.

Comment: @HelloCW Is there any error message?

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the latest version of the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack) first.

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val application: Application,
) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}
```

or

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
  @ApplicationContext private val mContext: Context,
) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But your code are not correct.

Comment: @HelloCW But it works in my case, is it a dependency version issue?

Comment: hilt_version = '2.41'