# Why does injection Context into ViewModel with Hilt cause the error "could not be resolved"?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I use `hilt_version = '2.41'` in my project,  I have read  the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565943/application-dependency-to-viewmodel-with-hilt).

I hope to inject `Context` into `ViewModel`, so I write Code A based that [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565943/application-dependency-to-viewmodel-with-hilt).

When I compile the Code A, I get the Result A, how can I fix the problems ?

**Code A**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val mContext: Context  
): ViewModel() {
   ...
}


@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {

}

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

**Result A**

```
Task :app:hiltJavaCompileFreeDebug
: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'info.dodata.soundmeter.presentation.UIApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule
      => element (METHOD): provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)
      => annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
      => type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
  
  If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.
: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'info.dodata.soundmeter.presentation.UIApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule
      => element (METHOD): provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)
      => annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
      => type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
  
  If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.
: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'info.dodata.soundmeter.presentation.UIApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule
      => element (METHOD): provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)
      => annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
      => type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
  
  If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.
: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'info.dodata.soundmeter.presentation.UIApp_HiltComponents.FragmentC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.FragmentModule
      => element (METHOD): provideFactory(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)
      => annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory
      => type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory
  
  If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.
```

**Added Content:**

To ladytoky0:

Thanks!

The following are my build.gradle, the project can work well when  `hilt_version = '2.40'`,and fails when `hilt_version = '2.41'`.

**App build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android { 
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}


dependencies {
    // Hilt dependencies
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
    ...
  
}
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
        hilt_version = '2.40'      
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"

        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: I find `hilt_version = '2.41' ` maybe cause the error, and `hilt_version = '2.40'` is OK

Comment: Also, try adding 

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the same result after I add `kapt {
 correctErrorTypes = true
}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had a similar problem and removing this should help:

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

More info [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3257)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on the dependencies. ([adding dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#kts))

On your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")
    }
}
```

On your app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1")
}

// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
 correctErrorTypes = true
}

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Also you can take a look to this codelab [android hilt](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#6)

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: why don't you use the 2.38.1 version?

Comment: it worked? on android dveloper site it is written that is 2.38.1. Maybe you could try all the code I wrote and tell if it works! :)

Comment: Thanks!  `hilt_version = '2.40'` is OK too.